# Odoo 16 modifies the Add Details action

Tags: python-3.9, odoo-16

Adding detail lines in Odoo 16 does not auto-save, is there any way to trigger auto-save when adding a detail line?

I tried modifying the write method and it didn't seem to work.

Is it possible to modify the front-end of the one2many field type of the form to control the trigger time of auto-save?

I don't know much about the front end of odoo16.

Comment: didn't auto save when you go away from the form or clic on others buttons?

Comment: I have one2many field on the form form, when I add the detail line, there is a button trigger above which must be saved first, the experience is relatively poor, what is the way to trigger auto-save?